# fisher.test all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite

Tags: r

I'm helping out a friend with statistic on R while not knowing it. I'm trying to do a simple `fisher.test(df)` so far I've been able to select the data he wants to analyse.
Below my code

from the `dim` function I understand that it is a 2 dimensions matrix

```r
library(data.table)
data = fread(myFILE, header = FALSE, select = c(9,46))

dim(data)
# [1] 68  2

print(data)
> print(d)
     V9          V46
 1: Question1 ? Question2 ?
 2: 30          No
 3: 25          Yes
 4: 24          Yes
 5: 25          Yes
 6: 27          Yes
 7: 27          Yes
 8: 25          Yes
 9: 26          Yes
10: 25          Yes
11: 24          Yes
12: 26          No
13: 24          Yes
14: 27          Yes
15: 26          Yes
16: 26          Yes
17: 26          Yes
18: 27          Yes
19: 26          Yes

data = d[-1,] # to remove the 1: Question...

fisher.test(data)
Error in fisher.test(data) : 
  all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite
```

What am I missing? Should I convert Yes/No to 1/0 ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: According to `?fisher.test`, you may need either `x - as a two dimensional contingency table in matrix or a factor object. y - a factor object; ignored if x is a matrix.`.  Try `fisher.test(table(data))`

Comment: It did the tricks thank you very much, you can answer the question and I'll note it as resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documention of `?fisher.test`, we can either pass `x` and `y` as two arguments.  If `x` is a `matrix` of contingency table, `y` argument is ignored.  Or else can be both `factor` columns.  Here, we can convert the 'data' into a frequency table with `table` applied on the two column data.table which returns a `table` object (which also inherits the `matrix` class)

```
fisher.test(table(data))

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  table(data)
p-value = 0.2092
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```